# TextFormField hidden by keyboard - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When focussing on the TextFormField, the keyboard hides over the TextFormField. I am using SingleScrollview with the Column widget. Below I attached a screenshot with coding. Please guide me in fixing this issue.

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _tabText(),
        isSignin ? _loginContainer() : _signUpContainer(),
      ],
    ),),),);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you want when enter email field that time also visible password field above keyboard?

Comment: Unable to visible password field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//Add this line "resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true," to your Scaffold and put your main 
    container in ScrollView.

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
   key: _scaffoldKey,
   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   body: SingleChildScrollView(    
      child: Container()
    ),
   );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove these properties of the `Scaffold`:

```
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

If you remove them, `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` will be `true` by default.

[`resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html)

> ...if there is an onscreen keyboard displayed above the scaffold, the
>   body can be resized to avoid overlapping the keyboard, which prevents
>   widgets inside the body from being obscured by the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the above solution but I got the same.

Comment: If you tap on the password field, the keyboard is over the password field?

Answer (score 0):

Try SingleChildScrollView() widget after scaffold() widget. wrap all widgets with SingleChildScrollView() widget after Scaffold() widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold( 
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already I declared all widgets inside the SingleChildScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I tried animation to avoid this:

```
ScrollController _scrollController;                                 //<==  

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'SignUpPage';
  @override
  _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {

//Implementing scrollController by detecting keyboard               //<==
  bool scrolled = false;
  _scrollListener() {
    if (!scrolled && MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
      scrolled = true;
    }
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0) {
      scrolled = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }
```