# Flutter TextField hidden by Keyboard, try many solution but not working

Tags: flutter, scroll, keyboard, textfield

When focussing on the TextField, the keyboard hides over the TextField. Below I attached a screenshot with code. Please guide me in fixing this issue.

**signup.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yfobs/utilities/desc.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'SignUpPage';
  @override
  _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topCenter, colors: [
          Color(0xFF832685),
          Color(0xFFC81379),
        ])),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 80,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "SignUp",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(60))),
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20, left: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                              height: 45,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 0, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                                  ]),
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.person,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: 'Full Name',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                              height: 45,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 0, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 0),
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                                  ]),
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.email,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: 'Email',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                              height: 45,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 0, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 0),
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                                  ]),
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.call,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: 'Mobile Number',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                              height: 45,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 0, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 0),
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                                  ]),
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.vpn_key,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: 'Password',
                                ),
                                obscureText: true,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Spacer(),

                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                elevation: 5.0,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                ),
                                color: Color(0xFFC81379),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Sign Up'.toUpperCase(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('HomePage');
                                },
                              ),
                            ),

                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new FlatButton(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 0, right: 16, left: 16),
                                        child: new Text(
                                          Desc.alreadyUser,
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context)
                                            .pushNamed('SignInPage');
                                      },
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

i am try with this **solution:**

[TextFormField hidden by keyboard - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694058/textformfield-hidden-by-keyboard-flutter)

[Flutter/Dart Scrolling textfield above keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839982/flutter-dart-scrolling-textfield-above-keyboard)

[in flutter page textfield hidden by keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196213/in-flutter-page-textfield-hidden-by-keyboard)

[TextField gets hidden when the keyboard pops in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176233/textfield-gets-hidden-when-the-keyboard-pops-in)

[Flutter Keyboard makes textfield hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335483/flutter-keyboard-makes-textfield-hide)

[Flutter TextFormField hidden by keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586892/flutter-textformfield-hidden-by-keyboard)

[When I select a Textfield the keyboard moves over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it)

Comment: Try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586892/flutter-textformfield-hidden-by-keyboard

Comment: already tried bro, i added links too, in my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you wrap the body of your Scaffold with SingleChildScrollView and wrap your Container with the ConstrainedBox

Here is the output that I get https://prnt.sc/qozsvc

Keyboard will still be on top of the textfields but by using SingleChildScrollView, screen will be scrollable so you can scroll down and see textfields again.

This solution works for me.

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
      child: Container(
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: i'll try, Not Working

Answer (score 1):

Hey There I fixed your issue using `Expanded` widget Just Wrap your `child content` with `Expanded` widget. and remove some extra column which we don't need, Try my **Below** code and let me know it is working or not

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yfobs/utilities/desc.dart';


    class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
      static String tag = 'SignUpPage';
      @override
      _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
    }

    class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          body: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topCenter, colors: [
                  Color(0xFF832685),
                  Color(0xFFC81379),
                ])),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: signUpCardUI(context),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    Widget signUpCardUI(BuildContext context){
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 80,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0),
              child: Text(
                "SignUp",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0, right: 20, left: 20),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                            height: 40,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 0, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                                ]),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.person,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                hintText: 'Full Name',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                            height: 40,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 0, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 0),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                                ]),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.email,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                hintText: 'Email',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                            height: 40,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 0, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 0),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                                ]),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.call,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                hintText: 'Mobile Number',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                            height: 40,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 0, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 0),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)
                                ]),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.vpn_key,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                hintText: 'Password',
                              ),
                              obscureText: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),

                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              elevation: 5.0,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              ),
                              color: Color(0xFFC81379),
                              child: Text(
                                'Sign Up'.toUpperCase(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('HomePage');
                              },
                            ),
                          ),

                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new FlatButton(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 0, right: 16, left: 16),
                                      child: new Text(
                                         Desc.alreadyUser,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context)
                                          .pushNamed('SignInPage');
                                    },
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  ),
                                ]),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: bro i want my page Scroll, your code give me this output https://prnt.sc/qoyt9u , your code reduce my Space, not Scroll My Page

Answer (score 0):

did you try using the form widget?
add child as SingleChildScrollView which can have textformfield.

Comment: Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Form(
      child: Container(
      .
      .
      .
i'll try like this

Comment: body>form>SingleChildScrollView>column>Textformfield.....
like this

Comment: kindly check online for form widgets - the above solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me
**signup.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yfobs/utilities/desc.dart';    

ScrollController _scrollController;                                 //<==  

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'SignUpPage';
  @override
  _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {

//Implementing scrollController by detecting keyboard               //<==
  bool scrolled = false;
  _scrollListener() {
    if (!scrolled && MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
      scrolled = true;
    }
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0) {
      scrolled = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }




  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    .
    .
    //rest is same
    .
    .
}
```