# Flutter: Unable to make the Form scroll when the Keyboard is open

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

In my application, I am using a `stack` and a `container`. Within the `container` i have a `form` and its fields. Below is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: LoginUI(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return LoginState();
  }
}

class LoginState extends State<LoginUI> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child:
         Stack(
          fit: StackFit.loose,
          children: <Widget>[
            SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/login_image.png"),
              ),
            ),

            Positioned(
              top: 275,
              child: Container(
                height: 600,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                            margin:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                            child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/images/logo_2.png"),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Form(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 40,
                              ),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
                                height: 36,
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Please enter some text';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                    ),
                                    hintText: "Phone",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 15,
                            ),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 36,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Please enter some text';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Password",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child: Text("Forgot Password?",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
                                          fontSize: 14.0,
                                          letterSpacing: 1.25,
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80))),
                                )),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              margin:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80),
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80))),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "LOGIN",
                                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                      // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                          SnackBar(
                                              content:
                                                  Text('Processing Data')));
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                              TextSpan(
                                text: "Not a member yet? ",
                                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',  fontSize: 14.0, letterSpacing: 0.25, color:Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80 )),
                              ),
                              TextSpan(
                                text: "Create an Account",
                                style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline,  fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',  fontSize: 14.0, letterSpacing: 0.25, color:Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80 ),
                              ),)
                            ]),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
        //child: Image.asset("assets/images/login_image.png"),
        );
  }

  Widget _buildForm() {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                    child: ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage("assets/images/email_24px.png"),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, bottom: 30)),
              ),
              Flexible(
                  flex: 7,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 80,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter some text';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        contentPadding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        hintText: "Email",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    child: ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage("assets/images/lock_24px.png"),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, bottom: 30),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                    flex: 7,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter some text';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          contentPadding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Password",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  child: Text(
                    "Forgot Password?",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 25, right: 10, bottom: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                    child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 45,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 72, 128, 100),
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        side:
                            BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 72, 128, 100))),
                    child: Text(
                      "LOGIN",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ))
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

My view is as follows

[image]

when the keyboard is open, the user must close it to access the `login` button. This is because this cannot be scrolled. I tried adding `SingleScrollView` and `ListView` below the main image and wrap the rest with it, but that didnt work. It only made the content disappear.

How can i make sure the `fORM` section is scrollable?

Comment: why don't use bottom sheet instead?

Comment: @JohnJoe: Haven't used it before. Also how to apply here?

Comment: I would suggest you use bottom sheet. It easy to apply,not that complicated. Between, you may try Selim's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap your whole widget with `SingleChildScrollView` and then `ConstrainedBox` as follows:

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
      child: Container(
        child: yourWidget()
```

You can see the related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59783374/12709039

Comment: Thank you, this did work. It can scroll until a lot of white space get available, so is there any way we can limit the scroll? This is to control the scrolling to view what is required to view, eliminating scrolling to the remaining white space at the bottom.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to fix that problem as well. I'll let you know if I can find any solution.